# Running .jar File Java 8

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I've run .jar files before, but I've encountered a "different" situation, and I'm not sure what to do. I'd appreciate if someone could help me out.

Previously, I programmed with Java 6 and Eclipse Juno exported all my programs to runnable jar files. I'd get a .jar file that I could run by just double clicking on it. The files always looked something like this (note the jar file icon):

[image: jar file generated by Eclipse Juno with Java 6]

Recently, I wrote a program in Java 8 with Eclipse Luna (Release 4.4.0) and exported it to a runnable jar file, and I got something different (note the different file icon):

[image: jar file generated by Eclipse Luna with Java 8]

It no longer runs when I double click it. Instead, my computer uncompresses the jar, as it would a zip file. I tried running it from terminal. I cd'd to the directory and typed

```
java -jar graph3D.jar
```

I got the following error message:

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile graph3D.jar
```

After uncompressing the jar file, I found a folder named META-INF with the manifest file, MANIFEST.MF in it. It was the only file that seemed to resemble an executable file. Do I have to do something with that?

Could someone explain how I can run the second jar file graph3D.jar? Is it something new with Java 8, or something different about Eclipse Luna, or something else?

(Both programs run fine in Eclipse, by the way)

Thanks for your time and help.

Edit:

Below was the dialog box Eclipse displayed if anyone is interested.

Selecting "Use .jar;*.zip" makes the filename "graph3D.jar;*.jar;*.zip" .

Selecting "Use .zip" makes the filename "graph3D.jar;*.zip"

Selecting "Cancel" doesn't let you go forward.

You'd have to manually delete the extra file extension.

[image]

Comment: What's with all the extensions `.jar;*.jar;*.zip`...?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm not sure... Eclipse just did that... It said "You have used the extension “.zip” at the end of the name. The standard extension is “.jar;*.zip”."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow when you exported the file, the filters for the file dialog box (`*.jar;*.zip`) got attached to the filename, which is `graph3D.jar;*.jar;*.zip`, not `graph3D.jar`. Java can't find it because it doesn't have the name you supplied. Rename the file and pay close attention next time you export; either you fat-fingered something, or you're triggering a significant bug that needs fixing.

Comment: Thanks chrylis! That fixed it now. I'm not sure why Eclipse added the *.jar;*.zip. I'll edit in the dialog that Eclipse gave me. I'll accept your answer as soon as stackoverflow lets me.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you will access the build folder after you've built your project on the IDE under your project folder (in your workspace) and copy both the libraries folder and the .jar and post them wherever you want the program to be "installed", you'll then have an executable jar that should run smoothly without problems, just as I said don't forget the lib folder.

Answer (score -1):

I think there is nothing new in Java 8 related with the running jar, I guess you need to check the the Eclipse export issues, it seems your classes are missing from your second jar file.